# seeing what commits my branch is ahead by and maybe blowing them away

Tags: git

When I do `git status` I get this:

```
On branch 1.0
Your branch is ahead of 'upstream/1.0' by 2 commits.
```

I would like to know which 2 commits my branch is ahead by and potentially remove them. Any ideas as to how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the difference in commits of two branches by this command.

```
git log branch1 --not branch2
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the `..` notation, like `HEAD..@{u}` or `@{u}..HEAD`, actually *means* that sort of `branch1 --not branch2` thing.  And, `@{u}` means "this branch's upstream" so `@{u}..HEAD` means "things in `HEAD` that are not in its upstream" which is precisely what the OP wants to see.

Answer (score 1):

`git log --graph --oneline --decorate` will show you both where your local HEAD is, and where the remote HEAD is for the branch you're currently on in ancestor order.

If *all* you are about are the SHAs, then you can use `git cherry -v upstream/1.0` to show a diff between your local branch and your remote branch (in this case, `upstream/1.0`).

You could also inspect the file differences between the two by `git diff upstream/1.0`, which will show you the file differences between the two branches.  That may be a little less useful, as one would hope that the commit messages contain pertinent information as to why the commit is there in the first place, but it can be handy.

Comment: this [doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) could be useful to i guess

Comment: I must have an out-of-date version of git since `--online` doesn't seem to be a valid option..

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be `--oneline`.  I've since made the correction.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: this is not correct, see the comments below - Andras.
"ahead of" is always the most recent commits, ie the top two listed by git log

Comment: You have to be a bit careful with this, because `git log` sorts commits by time-stamp by default, and you can (deliberately or, by having your computer clock go wrong, accidentally) have commits with unusual timestamps.  But usually this is correct.

Comment: That's not true. If you made changes to your local branch two weeks ago but had not pushed them and then did a `git pull` when other commits had been made more recently than yours your "ahead of" commits would not be the top two. Remember, `git pull` is `git fetch` + `git merge`.

Comment: right you are.  I remembered that case as some variant of "you have commits, respectively", but I just tried it and it is as you say.